# How to create JSON array based on fields from SQL table? (Node.js - MsSQL)

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, json, sql-server

I have a project based on **Node.js** and **Microsoft SQL server**. There is only one table in the database and I need to get a **JSON** object based on it's records.

The table looks like:

[image]

Here we can see that there are records with identical fields. Let's say the table is named "Table1".
We need to make a query to get JSON of the following form:

```
{
  "animal": {
    "fish": ["shark"],
    "insect": ["fly", "wasp"]
  },
  "plant": {
    "wild": ["pine"],
    "cultural": ["apple"]
  },
  "human": {
    "adult": ["unemployed"],
    "kid": ["studying"]
  }
}
```

That is, I need to get not the records themselves, but generate a menu based on these records.
The connection to the database is made using **mssql**:

```
router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    await sql.connect(`mssql://${config.get('SQL_USER')}:${config.get('SQL_PASSWORD')}@${config.get('HOST')}/${config.get('DATABASE')}`);
    const data = await sql.query`THE_SQL_QUERY`;
    res.json(data);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    res.status(500).send('Server Error');
  }
});
```

Can you please tell me if it is possible to execute a query in order to get such a json at the output?
I do not have such deep knowledge of **SQL**, I will be grateful if you tell me.

Thanks for attention!

Comment: You cannot get a JSON output like that by doing a pure SQL query. You need to use an ORM or process your data after getting from SQL query to achieve that

Comment: You can get the *column names* as *keys*, something like `{ "category" : { "name" : "animal", "sub_category" : { "name" : "fish", "sub_sub_category" : [ "shark" ] } } }` fairly easily. It's exceedingly difficult to get *data* into *keys*.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I don't need to get just such a json - I need to get at least some object, which can then be processed using JavaScript methods, which I know well. I can pull everything from SQL and generate this json on the server, but the table is very big - 17000 records.